# Show that there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $A_N \subseteq U$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of nonempty compact subset of $\mathbb R$ with $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$. Let $A=\cap_{n\in \mathbb N}A_n$ Let $U $ be an open subset of $\mathbb R$ such that $A\subseteq U.$ Show that there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $A_N \subseteq U$.

**My attempt** 
$A=\cap_{n\in \mathbb N}A_n \subseteq A_n, \forall n\in \mathbb N.$

Since each $A_n$ is closed and bounded by Heine Borel Theorem. Hence, $A$ is also bounded. Arbitrary intersection closed subset of $\mathbb R$ is closed. Then, $A$ is closed.
Hence, By Heine Borel Theorem $A$ is compact. I don't know how to proceed from here. May I get help?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $A_n\nsubseteq U$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, we can pick a point $x_n\in A_n\setminus U$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Now use the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ to get a contradiction. You’ll need to use the fact that $A_0$ is compact. (My $\Bbb N$ includes $0$; if yours does not, replace $A_0$ by $A_1$.)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for contradiction $A_n \not \subseteq U$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then pick $x_n \in A_n \setminus U$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $A_n \subseteq A_0$ for every $n$, $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq A_0$, and by the compactness of $A_0$, there is a convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges. For convenience let $\{x_n\}$ now refer to the convergent subsequence instead, and let $x$ be the limit point. Notice that for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$, then for all $n \geq \mathbb{N}$, $x_n \in A_N$. So $\{x_n\}_{n \geq N}$ is a convergent subsequence of each $A_N$, and hence the limit $x$ is in each $A_N$. Thus, since $A = \cap_{N \in \mathbb{N}}A_N$, $x \in A$ as well. Since $A \subseteq U$, $x \in U$. But then by the definition of convergence, there must be some $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq M$, $x_n \in U$. But this directly contradicts that we chose each $x_n$ to be in $A_n \setminus U$. By contradiction, we're done.

Note: By passing to the convergent subsequence and technically abusing a bit of notation, I sidestepped some finnicky indexing management that you'll have to do. I'll leave that to you. The general idea remains as above.

Answer (score 1):

$A_1 \cap U^{c} \subseteq \bigcup_{n \geq 2} A_n^{c}$. Since $A_1 \cap U^{c}$ is a closed subset of $A_1$ it is compact. This open cover therefore has a finite subcover. If $A_1 \cap U^{c} \subseteq \bigcup_{2\leq n \leq N} A_n^{c}$ the $A_N \subseteq U$.